# Can not resize and drag jquery popup dialog popup in ie9 standard mode

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-dialog

Not able to resize and drag jquery popup dialog (jQuery UI Dialog 1.8.1) popup in ie9 standard mode, but its working perfectly in ie9 compatibility mode.

Unfortunately I can not upgrade the jquery core (1.4.2) which is using now.

Is any other  workaround without update jquery core?

Thanks,
Jaison

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create the dialog?
That would help us find a solution.

Comment: @Alex Code for reference http://jsfiddle.net/jjkktr/G2X3w/